# Rewriting a Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

Here is what I currently have:

```
from s in domainThreads.Values
where (s.IsAvailable)
select s;
```

but I'm still learning Linq and believe that I can get it all on one line.  Does the following look correct?

```
domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable).Any();
```

Do I need the `.Any()`?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Is it returning what you expect? If not, post *that* as your question.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio with me.  I'm merely reading and learning the lingo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any()` returns a boolean indicating whether or not there are any entities in the given set.

The equivalent of your original LINQ expression would simply be:

```
domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable)
```

Answer (score 2):

The two are not equivalent.

The first returns all `Values` where `s.IsAvailable`.

The second returns whether there are any such values.

A correct conversion is:

```
domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable)
```

Which translates to:

```
domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable).Select(s => s)
```

Which is what the original query gets transformed to anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Any()` -- that will return a `bool` indicating if any of elements satisfy the condition.

Instead, just do:

```
domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable)
```

is enough.

Answer (score 1):

[Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) returns a `bool` value, but your original query returns a data set. So just use `Where()`

```
var result = domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable);
```

`Any()` would be helpful when you just need ensure that at least single item satisfies a condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var obj = domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable == true).Select(o => o);
```

Comment: i found that some one voted down this answer. Is there is any mistake in this answer?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I didn't see any mistake. The only thing is that you don't get an object, but an IEnumerable<T> as a result. The variable name obj is misleading.

Comment: ohh.. var obj will give you anonymous type objects

Comment: It is not a compiler error. But the variable name obj let you think you get a single object back which is not true. You get all domainthreads where IsAvailable is true.

Comment: it may be a list but i asign the return type as var which is a anonymous type....

Comment: As I said, it's the variable name, not the type which is misleading. Of course you can give it any name like var i = new ArrayList(); In my opinion the name of the variable should reflect it's content.

Answer (score 1):

If you call [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) it returns `bool` which indicates that you have at least one item.

```
domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable);
```

- this expression is enough and it is equivalent to the LINQ statement.

Answer (score 1):

`Any()` returns a boolean that is true if the result contains one or more items.

```
var elements = from s in domainThreads.Values
where (s.IsAvailable)
select s;
//elements now contains a list of objects.
```

This is equivalent to:

```
elements = domainThreads.Where(s => s.IsAvailable);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks but is not the same. The result is boolean and returns true if the collection contains any elements.

You could write something like this, but is it really worth the effort?

```
var result = domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable).Select(s => s);
```

or shorter:

```
var result = domainThreads.Values.Where(s => s.IsAvailable);
```

EDIT: if you just want to have one line of code you can also write:

```
from s in domainThreads.Values where s.IsAvailable select s;
```

It's much more readable and generates to the same code in the end.